# How to make virtualhost section according to URL in same port?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

One apache httpd virtualhost section for mod_wsgi:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    WSGIScriptAlias /pf /home/services/pf/pf.wsgi 
    WSGIDaemonProcess pf user=wsgi user=operator processes=10 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}
    WSGIProcessGroup pf

    ErrorLog "/home/log/pf-error.log"
    TransferLog "/home/log/pf-access.log"

   <Directory /home/services/pf>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to add another wsgi app 'cf' for '/confirm' URL 
and `ErrorLog`, `TransferLog` for 'cf'.

Like this..

```
WSGIScriptAlias /cf /home/services/cf/cf.wsgi 
WSGIDaemonProcess cf user=wsgi user=operator processes=10 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP}

WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}
WSGIProcessGroup cf

ErrorLog "/home/log/cf-error.log"
TransferLog "/home/log/cf-access.log"
```

How to make virtualhost section according to URL(/pf, /cf) in same port?
Just make new virtualhost section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have the one access/error log per VirtualHost. You can't therefore have separate logs based on sub URL under the one site. Creating a separate `VirtualHost` will not help as that would have to have a different `ServerName`.

If you can give up the log file requirement, you can do:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    WSGIScriptAlias /pf /home/services/pf/pf.wsgi 
    WSGIDaemonProcess pf user=wsgi user=operator processes=10 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIScriptAlias /cf /home/services/cf/cf.wsgi 
    WSGIDaemonProcess cf user=wsgi user=operator processes=10 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

   <Directory /home/services/pf>
      WSGIProcessGroup pf
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

   <Directory /home/services/cf>
      WSGIProcessGroup cf
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/home/log/error.log"
    TransferLog "/home/log/access.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

It is better to set `WSGIApplicationGroup` to `%{GLOBAL}` when you only delegate one WSGI application to each daemon process group.